# Limitation of number of features in GMM

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-moments

I am new to GMM training. I could see from the [link](http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php/GRT/GMMClassifier) as below

> The main limitation of the GMM algorithm is that, for computational
>   reasons, it can fail to work if the dimensionality of the problem is
>   too high (i.e. greater than 6 dimensions for instance).

Could you anyone please provide a reference/justification for the claim. I am planning to have GMM trainer for a maximum of 16 features. I would like to know in which scenarios this will happen.